# links not working on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile, hyperlink

I've been using one page scroll plugin (https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) on my portfolio website and not sure if that is an issue or something else but none of my links are working on the mobile devices (physically tested only on iphone 4s so far and in chrome using toggle device mode).

You can view the dev version of the website here http://www.michaelahercogova.com/portfolio_mh

Any help would be highly appreciate!

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Have you tried [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead? That should work with no problem and it provides you with plenty of more options.

Comment: no, i fixed it at the end, see the post below...it's working great all over now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, if anyone has the same problem, you need to comment out event.preventDefault(); in touchstart function in order to make other links on the page work on mobile devices.